# In x86 (assembly), is a [repz retq] valid?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an extremely simple test binary that I'm looking at with objdump.  I'm seeing an assembly instruction that confuses me.  The code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return 42;
}
```

When I do an `objdump -d test`, I see an interesting function:

```
00000000004004a0 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
  4004a0:       80 3d 85 0b 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x200b85(%rip)       # 60102c <_edata>
  4004a7:       75 11                   jne    4004ba <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x1a>
  4004a9:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004aa:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004ad:       e8 7e ff ff ff          callq  400430 <deregister_tm_clones>
  4004b2:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004b3:       c6 05 72 0b 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x200b72(%rip)        # 60102c <_edata>
  4004ba:       f3 c3                   repz retq 
  4004bc:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

So 2nd from the bottom there, the instruction is `f3 c3`, or `repz retq`.  Now looking up `f3` in the x86 instruction set reference, I see this is a legacy prefix.

[image]

[image]

So `c3 / ret` is certainly not one of the listed valid instructions to precede it with it appears, so I'm wondering why my binary is doing this at all.

I'm executing gcc(4.8.5) like this:

```
gcc -g -Wall  -c src/test.c -o obj/test.o
gcc -g -Wall  obj/test.o -o bin/test
```

Comment: Very interesting, you're right, this is a duplicate.  For anyone who is curious, in the linked blog of the top answer to the question linked by Michael above, *...this form is preferred to the simple ret either when it is the target of any kind of branch, conditional (jne/je/...) or unconditional (jmp/call/...), or when it directly follows a conditional branch.* As you can see from the 2nd instruction in this function, it is indeed the target of a conditional jump.

Comment: `gcc -march=intel`, or any specific arch other than AMD K8/K8, will just use normal `ret` without padding, even when the `ret` is a branch target/fallthrough.  E.g. use `gcc -O3 -march=native`.

Comment: Actually you're looking at code from the CRT start files linked into your executable, that run before/after `main()`.  They're not recompiled every time, and were probably compiled with the default `-march=generic`, or written by hand in asm.